# If Not ComboBox.SelectedItem = "String" (Or) "String2" (Or) "String3"

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wanted to make an application that when I wrote some item that is not in the combobox, it would show a messagebox saying it was to choose one of the items in the combobox.

I tried this, it probably has nothing to do with what I wanted :P

```
    If Not ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Português - BR" Or "English - US" Or "Espanol - ES" Then
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If
```

Comment: `If ` works with *expressions*; "English - US" is not an expression.  See [If...Then...Else Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement).  You should be using `OrElse`.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Apart from anything else, how can the item selected in the `ComboBox` possibly not be one of the items in the `ComboBox`?

Comment: `Or` absolutely does NOT work the way you thought. Revise your book or whatever tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?  If not, I'm not sure I understand  your problem.

```
        If Not ((ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Português - BR") _
            Or (ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "English - US") Or (ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Espanol - ES")) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the issues that others have identified in the `If` statement, the real problem is that the `If` is not the right way to constrain the user to only select items from the list.  The right way to do this is to set the options on the Combo control so the user cannot enter their own item.

If you're using the Windows Forms control, set the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`.

If you're using the WPF control, set `IsEditable` to false.